# jQuery DatePicker conflict with DatePicker from included file

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two php pages, search.php and result.php.  Both of these pages use jQuery and both have jQueryUI datepickers and work perfectly independently of each other.

I've included search.php in my result.php file because I want to use it as a sidebar, now I seem to have some kind of conflict because the datepicker in search.php has stopped working, in that the calendar doesn't appear and so is unusable.  jQuery is working in both files, I've confirmed this by printing to the screen.  Also if I remove the datepicker initialisation code from result.php (leaving other jQuery code I also have in the page) then the other datepickers from search.php begin to work again.  The IDs are unique, I'm using noConflict to make sure jQuery can work on both pages and as I say, it does - the only issue is when I initialise the datepicker on result.php it causes those in search.php to stop working.

Using IE's JS debugger I can see that the datepicker in result.php is initialised first, then the others get initialised.  There is no script error or warning so I don't know where else to go!  Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**
I've stripped out all non-related code so I can upload it here.  There's two files, testSearch.php and testResult.php.  The testResult.php includes test.search.php as it will be displayed as a sidebar.  Both pieces of script work in isolation but once both are enabled, the datepicker in testSearch.php stops working.

testResult.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <!-- jQuery -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
 <div id="sidebar"><?php include 'testSearch.php';?></div>
 <div id="content">
  <div id="availCal"></div>
 </div>

 <script>
  var jResult = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  jResult(document).ready(function() {
   jResult( "#availCal" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    firstDay: 1,
    numberOfMonths: 3,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    showCurrentAtPos:1
   });
  });
 </script>

</body>
```

testSearch.php

```
<!-- include jquery and jquery ui -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<label for="arrPicker">Arrival date:</label><br />
<input class="dateSelect" type="text" id="arrPicker" name="arr" value="<?php echo $arr; ?>" readonly />

<script>
 var jSearch = jQuery.noConflict(true);
 jSearch(document).ready(function() {
  jSearch('.dateSelect').each(function(){
   jSearch(this).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    constrainInput: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    minDate: 1,
    showAnim: "slideDown"
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

As an asside, am I correct in leaving out the doctype/head/body tags from the file which will be included (testSearch.php)?  I assume they aren't necessary since testResult.php already has those tags and testSearch.php will just be injected into that.

Comment: Show us your `php` code especially the `include`

Comment: There's quite a lot of code though, anything specific I should show?  Wouldn't want to spam it all out!

Comment: both pages have jQuery which runs on document.ready, is that a problem?

Comment: I've added the php code from the include and the main page if you could have a look @Madhu ?

Answer (score 0):

Try use

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    $('body').on('focus',"#yourTagId", function(){ $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#yourTagId').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });});
    });
});
```

Comment: The only way I could get my page to work is to initalise the datepicker used in testResult.php within testSearch.php.  Don't know what the issue was and this isn't my ideal solution, but it'll have to do